# How to convert RECORD type parameter to XML or json in oracle?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, object, dynamic

R_Al.op_record is a user defined record type in oracle. I can not compile the following code.  What I want is to convert the user defined RECORD type in to an xml or json without referring to its attributes one by one. Is this possible to do? Can we do this using dynamic sql?

The compilation error I get is

Error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'XMLTYPE'

```
    TYPE op_record IS RECORD (
        operation_row_count           BINARY_INTEGER,
        operation_id_tab              number_type,
        operation_no_tab              number_type,
        operation_description_tab     char_50_type);

    PROCEDURE Update_S(
       op_rec_ IN R_Al.op_record)
    IS
        v_xml   SYS.XMLTYPE;
        mytype R_Al.op_record;
    BEGIN
        mytype := op_rec_;
        v_xml := xmltype(mytype);
    END Update_S;
```

Comment: "I can not compile" - please include the full error(s) you get. What you've described [seems to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=105019ab6471a8a18dbb85ec43870202), as long as `op_record` is an object type as you said (not a PL/SQL record type), and the procedure owner either owns or had direct-grant privileges on it. Please also include all the relevant DDL.

Comment: I have updated the above question. Sorry its a user defined record type.